# iPhone to Android/PC bluetooth connection

Tags: android, ios, iphone, bluetooth

I have read iOS 3 does only support audio transfer over Bluetooth.

Are dataconnections supported in newer iOS versions that send commands twoways, instead of a oneway filetransfer (I'm thinking of gaming)?

Do newer iOS versions support connections to Android phones or computers? Is Bluetooth backwards compatible, so I can hook a BT 4 device to a BT other device (and vice versa)?
If there are limitations, what are they, how can I possibly circumvent them?

Would Wifi gaming be a better solution to inter-Android-iPhone-PC communications? Would this introduce more latency or other problems? And on what devices is it possible to host a game then (considering one would not require a router)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bluetooth profiles supported by iOS is listed [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647)

For Gaming you can use the iOS GameKit APIs for peer to peer connectivity using bluetooth. 
Note - GameKit will work only with iOS devices (So you can't have iOS and Android talk over Gamekit)

Bluetooth is backward compatible in general (depending on what mode you are using) 
BT 4.0 has 2 modes - Classic BT + Low Energy BT dual mode or Low Energy only singe mode, Devices are of 2 types - Ones supporting both modes (called dual mode devices or Smart Ready Devices) and ones with only Low Energy mode (Called single mode BT 4.0 or BT smart device) 
Then there are the legacy BT devices supporting the Classic mode only (BT 3.x 2.x 1.x )
So a BT Smart device can talk to another smart device (as long as the support the required roles) and also to BT smart ready devices. 
A BT 4.0 dual mode device can talk to legacy BT devices (BT 3.x, 2.x etc) using the Classic BT modes / profiles and it is backward compatible.
But a BT 4.0 smart device cannot talk to a legacy BT classic mode only device (Like 3.x , 2.x etc)

WiFi seems like a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive response. Is it possible to create a PAN without the GameKit API (and nonroot) from the bottom up so it -can- communicate with Android/PC? Or does Apple not provide this possibility? I find it hard to find this info on the web..

Comment: @Dennis Mathews I am trying to get my app connected to Mac/Windows sothat I could control the Speaker and the Mic on the iPhone for a VOIP software, is this possible? Thanks in advance